# Continuous delta hedge formula

Tags: volatility, black-scholes, implied-volatility, hedging

When we buy a call and continuously delta hedge using some implied volatility $\sigma_i$, what is the formula for our aggregate profit given that the actual realized volatility is $\sigma_r$?

Say $S_0 = 1000, \sigma_i = 0.25, \mu = 0.10$, and the call has expiry a year from now.

How does the formula look like in terms of $\sigma_r$? What happens if $\sigma_r =0$? $> \sigma_i$? $< \sigma_i$?

Comment: See this answer https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33205/delta-hedge-value-formula for the daily P&L. For the overall P&L you integrate this from 0 to T.

Comment: Chapter 12 "How to Delta Hedge" in Wilmott's "Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance" discusses this problem in detail. In particular it shows how your hedging p&l differs when using either the implied or the estimated (true) volatility for computing the hedge ratio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33345/how-would-you-arbitrage-this?noredirect=1&lq=1. @LocalVolatility maybe you should write this as an answer so we can indeed mark these as duplicates?

Answer (score 6):

This is a slightly extended version of my comment that summarizes the main result of the reference that I provided.

This problem is discussed in detail in Chapter 12 of Wilmott (2006), which is based on the paper Ahmad and Wilmott (2005). See also the related Question 9 in Carr (2005).

In your case, you are selling and delta hedging the option using the implied volatility $\sigma_{(i)}$ while the actual volatility of the underlying asset is $\sigma_{(r)}$. Your portfolio profit and loss is given by the sum of value changes of (i) the derivative and (ii) the hedging position, both using the implied volatility. We have

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d} \Pi_t = \mathrm{d}V_t^{(i)} - \Delta_t^{(i)} \mathrm{d}S_t - r \left( V_t^{(i)} - \Delta_t^{(i)} S_t \right) \mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}

Since

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}V_t^{(i)} = \frac{\partial V^{(i)}}{\partial t} \mathrm{d}t + \underbrace{\frac{\partial V^{(i)}}{\partial S}}_{= \Delta^{(i)}} \mathrm{d}S_t + \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\frac{\partial^2 V^{(i)}}{\partial S}}_{=\Gamma^{(i)}} \mathrm{d} \langle S \rangle_t,
\end{equation}

we get

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\Pi_t = \left( \frac{\partial V^{(i)}}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma_{(r)}^2 S_t^2 \frac{\partial^2 V^{(i)}}{\partial S^2} - r \left( V_t^{(i)} - \Delta_t^{(i)} S_t \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}

Now we use that $V^{(i)}$ satisfies the Black-Scholes PDE

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial V^{(i)}}{\partial t} + r S_t \underbrace{\frac{\partial V^{(i)}}{\partial S}}_{=\Delta^{(i)}} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma_{(i)}^2 S_t^2 \underbrace{\frac{\partial^2 V^{(i)}}{\partial S^2}}_{=\Gamma^{(i)}} - r V^{(i)} = 0
\end{equation}

to obtain

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\Pi_t = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sigma_{(r)}^2 - \sigma_{(i)}^2 \right) S_t^2 \Gamma^{(i)} \mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}

I.e. over each short interval, your profit and loss is proportional to the difference in realized to implied variance times the current gamma (computed using the implied volatility). While $\mathrm{d}\Pi_t$ is deterministic, the overall hedging profit and loss over the lifetime of the option is path-dependent. Its absolute value is higher for paths that fluctuate around the strike (where the gamma is higher).

**References**

Ahmad, Riaz and Paul Wilmott (2005) "Which Free Lunch Would You Like Today, Sir? Delta Hedging, Volatility Arbitrage and Optimal Portfolios," Wilmott Magazine, available [here](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ajacquie/IC_AMDP/IC_AMDP_Docs/Literature/Wilmott.pdf)

Carr, Peter (2005) "FAQs in Option Pricing Theory", Working Paper, available [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.27.896)

Wilmott, Paul (2006) *Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance*, Vol. 1: Wiley, 2nd Edition